# Python Web3 - 'str' object has no attribute 'request_func'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web3py

Trying to call a function that takes a parameter from my contract on BSC. The parameter is an address. The signing of the transaction goes well but when I get to send_raw_transaction I get hit with "'str' object has no attribute 'request_func'".

Using send_transaction alone gives off this error : "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

```
import json

from web3.auto import w3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
from web3 import Web3

# Set up the connection to the network.
bsc = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/'))
bsc.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
print(bsc.isConnected())

w3 = Web3('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/')

            nonce = bsc.eth.get_transaction_count('ADDRESS_ETC')

            hex_string = bytes.fromhex('ADDRESS_ETC')

            privateKey = "PRIVATE_KEY_ETC"
            account = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey)

            unicorn_txn = contract.functions.myFunction(
                hex_string
            ).build_transaction({
                'chainId': 56,
                'gas': 70000,
                'maxFeePerGas': w3.toWei('2', 'gwei'),
                'maxPriorityFeePerGas': w3.toWei('1', 'gwei'),
                'nonce': nonce,
                'from': account.address,
            })

            print(unicorn_txn)
            
            signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(unicorn_txn, private_key=privateKey)

            signed_txn.rawTransaction

            signed_txn.r

            signed_txn.s

            signed_txn.v

            w3.eth.send_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

Expected the transaction to go through, it didn't

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have

```
w3 = Web3(url)
```

you need to have

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url))
```

This is a tricky one, as the problem doesn't appear until you try to make certain calls using w3.